# Javascript Catch In Then Promises

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure this out. I have a promise like this

```
 function Function1 () {
   return fetch()
   .then((xx) => )
   .catch(error => throw(error));
}
```

Use this Function1 promise in another file.

```
Function1()
.then((xx) => ()
.catch((error) => {
  console.log('I want to Catch that stupid error here');
});
```

Why can't I get the error message thrown from the Function1 promise in the catch error where I am calling this Function1() ?

Any of your kind help and comments will be highly appreciated, Gracious :)

Comment: for a start `.catch(error => throw(error));` is redundant, don't need it, get rid of it - invalid syntax anyway

Comment: `.then((xx) => ()` - missing something?

Comment: you have a missing " ) " Function1().then(xx => ()).catch((error) => { console.log('I want to Catch that stupid error here');});

Comment: adjusting for syntax errors (which promises wont help with) - your code works just fine - https://jsfiddle.net/Ltg9xcpL/ - and it works equally fine if you remove the redundant baseball game (catch and throw) - https://jsfiddle.net/Ltg9xcpL/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `throw` inside `.then` function.

```js
// Here is Promise then throw example

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(5);
}).then(result => {
  throw 'Err';
})
.catch(error => { 
  console.log(error); 
  throw error;
});
```